# How to change the Color of the hovered Select-Option in FireFox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I want to change the Color of the hovered Select-Option in FireFox which has default blue background and white foreground.

I tried:

```
<select name="select" size="1">
   <option>0</option>
   <option class="test">1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
```

```
.test:hover {
    color:green;
    background-color:yellow;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

But it doesn't work. See [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oliholz/zagzH/1/).
A FireFox specific solution is sufficient.

Comment: It seems you cannot do that 

Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color

Comment: Unfortunately, you Just Can't Do It.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I can set an Image as Backround.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oliholz/zagzH/8/)

But it is only painted on :hover, when I exit the mouse from the option it will by system rendered.

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT` elements are rendered by the OS, not HTML. You cannot style this element.

You can use a HTML+CSS replacement using JavaScript to simulate SELECT though.

Comment: Why does `text-decoration:underline;` work? And a global Select-Color change works also for the options.

Comment: +1 same idea and quicker than me. I was searching through my bookmarks to find the plugin link!

Comment: SEELCT is probably one of the largest inconsistencies in CSS. Some browsers have allowed some styling, but there is no standard. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done with CSS alone. I recommend a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin replacement for the `<select>`

Comment: The Problem is: The `<select>` is generated by GWT and i cannot use more libaries for this Problem.

Comment: Ah ok, you might want to add that information to the question :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need to work with CSS combinators like this:

```
select>option.test:hover
{
    color: #1B517E;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Basically you are specifying this:

Parent > children . class : event

All children in select tags inside which options with the class ".test" will have the style specified in brackets.

IMPORTANT: It works on Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Here's a reference can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp