# How to change the backcolor of combobox selected gighlighting dropdownItem in c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox

When I have click on combobox, all the dropdown items will be dropped down and when the mouse hovers on an item it will highlighte in default blue color. Now I want to change the default blue color to as my wish. Please anybod help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, then you can do it using custom ComboBox, or [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event on Microsoft's ComboBox, in WPF you can override Color in XAML, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override this style. Check following questions for explanation:

- [Changing <select> highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color)
- [How to change the Color of the hovered Select-Option in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027551/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-hovered-select-option-in-firefox)

However you can try to simulate dropdown by creating it with js and provide any style you want. Check links to get example:

- http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/
- http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/