# Custom combobox design to php website

Tags: javascript, css, combobox

I need to create a combobox with custom item's design to use in a php website.

however i can't figure out what to use since there's no way to do it by simple css (that i know of)

It should look somewhat like this:

[Desired combobox design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgf0.jpg)

Comment: You can find all sorts of this here: http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu

EDIT sorry, I wasn't looking good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) to see how to stye a combobox with pure css. Just adapt the properties as you wish regarding color etc.

Comment: It helped me but i need to change the item background color as i hover it(you can see in the image i posted above)

Comment: For the item background on hover use: select:hover { background-color: red; } in your css file

Comment: That just changes the BG of the SELECT. I want to change the BG of the OPTION as i hover it.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that point. use select option:hover { background: #ff0000; }. Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/1965084 As stated here it might lead you into some problems to reliable style form control across different browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667192/1965084

Comment: Worked perfectly. however as you stated before, it doesnt work in some browsers as i was testing

Comment: Ok thats bad, if javascript is possible for you, consider using some jquery controls like this: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown If my answer helped you, please mark it as solved with the check mark on the left :)

Comment: i'm going to give a try to that jquery plugin. anyway, i'll solve it easily from now on, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it literally took me no longer than 5 seconds on Google.

Have a look at this tutorial here:

[Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/)