# How to change color of selection in select option?

Tags: css, html-select

I'm trying to change color of selection in select option.
I was trying to do this:

```
option::selection {background: #ccc;}
option::-moz-selection {background: #ccc;}
option::-webkit-selection {background: #ccc; color:#fff;}
```

But it doesn't work. This works only for simple text, not to option.
Is there any way to change color of selection?
I dont need to change background of selected option. I need to change color of selection.

Comment: A *possible* duplicate of [Changing <select> highlight color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color), while I think this *is* a duplicate question, I'm not entirely certain due to the vague descriptions in both this, and that, question.

Comment: Why are you working with select? If you want some super cool styles you should start using html lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: I don't believe there's a reliable solution that works across browsers/devices without using a library such as Select2. I'd suggest looking at this (stackoverflow post)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript] regarding styling of selects.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you expected.

```js
function ChangedSelection()
{
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
var color =document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
y.style.color=color;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="ChangedSelection()" style="Color:red;">
    <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one maybe it will be helpful for you.

```
select{
    margin:40px;
    background: yellow;
    color:#000;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
option:not(:checked) { 
    background-color: #FFF; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option val="">Select Option</option>
    <option val="1">Option 1</option>
    <option val="2">Option 2</option>
    <option val="3">Option 3</option>
    <option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Demo JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/yfg8vdme/

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/287/

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.mySelect').change(function () {
    $(this).find('option').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
}).trigger('change');
```

HTML

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, this works only for background of option itself. And I need to change directly color of selection, not color of option.

Comment: Technically, that answer uses jquery, not javascript.