# Change <select> option default color

Tags: html, css

I'm using a `dropdown` but the problem is with `CSS`. On `hover` of all the options, the default color of option is blue. Can I change this color through `CSS` or by any means?

Comment: without using any extra plugins

Comment: You understand that on different devices that list looks differently, don't you? And even some of those devices do not have :hover as a concept.

Comment: select option:hover {
 padding-left: 25px;
 width: 270px;
 color: green !important;
}

Comment: This is most of the time, an OS specific behavior. Also different browsers behave differently in this case. Sometimes, CSS won't affect because it will get overridden by the OS itself. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color) also

Comment: do you want to change the background colour ?

Comment: This can't be done with HTML and css only but it looks like you [can do it with javascript/jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OS and browsers override `<select>` and `<option>` controls, each in a different way, and it's an OS-centric control (unlike `<input>` boxes, which are mainly customizable and can be fully changed by your website). You won't be able to change it (not consistently anyway), but a good solution would be to implement something as [Bootstrap's dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) or a jQuery plugin such as [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which give you dropdowns that are completely customizable and way more flexible anyway.