# select list hover color for all browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have select list and I am using *bootstrap*.

It is having its default blue color which I want to overwrite.
I want to define custom color on `:hover`, *selection* and clicked(`:focus` and `:active`.).

***Some body told me its not possible to achieve using css.
So, I tried to achieve this using javascript or jQuery. But it doesn't work. Now ***

But it's not working for hover. Please see the demo.

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m2sY/37/)

[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: have you checked this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color

Comment: Because you're still trying to alter `<select>` default properties using *jQuery* or *JS*, as I've recommended you to use [**Dropkick**](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick) to the very first post of yours, viz exactly the same as this one.

And on SO, always edit your original post instead of asking another one with same query.

Comment: Yes i tried but still i struggling and i dont want to use any more third party js

Comment: Does it supports in IE as well ??

Comment: Yes, I'm using it in my application, and its highly customized.

Comment: ok I will look into that.. Thanks