# Need to change the highlighted blue color on select drop down to any color without using JavaScript/jquery (mainly in chrome)

Tags: css, html

**Kindly read my `Note Points` as my main problem exists there only.**

As I am using a normal  tag in html.

Code as follows:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here, as we all know that the values on hover, the color that comes by default is blue (i.e. a system color) But I want a color other than blue.

**Note:**
1. It should work mainly in the Chrome browser.
2. Avoid JavaScript/jquery code.

Thanks in advance pals !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colour of blue highlight on select box dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown)

Comment: @GoGoris This issue to be resolved without using javaScript and JQuery. So only have raised this Question in plain HTMl & CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing <select> highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color)

Answer (score 2):

[Changing <select> highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color/1667105)

Changing the blue color on the options is not possible using css

Comment: More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms